# How to add conditions in a Multibinding string block? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, string, xaml, multibinding, string-formatting

I am trying to format the title of my Application but it seems some basic WPF details escape me. Here is my code:

```
<Window.Title>
   <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
      <Binding Path="Shell.Workbench.Title" />
      <Binding Path="Shell.Workbench.CurrentFileName" />
   </MultiBinding>
</Window.Title>
```

The problem is that my second field can sometimes be en empty string. If that is the case how can I hide the dash between them?

Example: If both strings exist, I have a title like this
                      *"Title - CurrentFileName"*.
         If second string is empty, I have
                      *"Title -"* 
         and I want to have just
                      **"Title"**.

Thank you

Comment: you can use a converter : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.converter.aspx and in it do the text manipulations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*this is an answer i've edited my commant
you can use a converter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.converter.aspx  and in it do the text manipulations

Comment: Thank you, I was able to fix my issue using your indications.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, ok it's just an alternative, because you are asking for a solutions with `MultiBinding` but I would create an additional property (for joining the strings) in the `ViewModel`, which behaves that way, and bind it to the view.

Every other method like `ValueConverters` wouldn't be worth the effort.